# Facing an issue during navigation from splash screen to home screen and splash screen to specific screen when tapped on push notification

Tags: flutter, dart, push-notification, sharedpreferences, variable-assignment

Below is the code for splash screen where it is checking for splash id value.if the splash id is "mainid" then after splash screen it should navigate to home screen(oktwrapper) else null. The reason for using null in else part is that when tapped on push notification it is calling getInitialMeassage() which is doing further navigation according to response of push notification.
But I am here facing an issue while navigating I am using shared preferences to set and get value to perform navigation but its not working as expected. I am sharing all splash-screen.dart , main.dart, notification.dart files please let me know for any soulutions:
Splash Screen.dart

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/logic/view_models/auth_manager.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/models/core/user_details.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/models/helper/service_locator.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/routes/router.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/theme/constants.dart';
import '../../../firebase_options.dart';
import 'package:yaml/yaml.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/main.dart';

import '../../push_notification/notification.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SplashScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SplashScreen> createState() => _SplashScreenState();
}

class _SplashScreenState extends State<SplashScreen> {
  @override
  void initState() {}

  _navigateLogin() async {
    var delay = await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 3000), () {});
    getIt<SharedPreferences>().getString('id');

    SharedPreferences shared = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    String? token = await getIt<SharedPreferences>().getString("token");
    // await initPlatformState();
    if (getIt<SharedPreferences>().getString('onboardViewed') == 'true') {
      if (getIt<SharedPreferences>().getString('token') == null ||
          getIt<SharedPreferences>().getString('id') == null) {
        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, getStarted);
      } else {
        // final mainid = getIt<SharedPreferences>().getString('mainid');
        // if (mainid == 'mainid') {
        //   Navigator.pushNamed(context, oktWrapper);
        // }
        final splashid =
            getIt<SharedPreferences>().getString('splashid').toString();
        String sid = splashid;
        final mainid = getIt<SharedPreferences>().getBool('mainid');
        // if (splashid == null) {
        //   Navigator.pushNamed(context, oktWrapper);
        // }

        // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
        // if (sid == null) {
        //   Navigator.pushNamed(context, oktWrapper);
        // }
        splashid == 'mainid' ? Navigator.pushNamed(context, oktWrapper) : null;

        // }

        // setState(() {
        //   splashid == false;
        // });
        print('the slpash id is -------------$splashid');

        String? userId = getIt<SharedPreferences>().getString('id');
        UserDetails? userInfo = await getIt<AuthManager>().getUInfo(userId);
      }
    } else {
      Navigator.pushNamed(context, onBoard);
    }
  }

  void navigatemain() {}
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _navigateLogin());
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colours.black,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            const SizedBox(height: 180),
            Container(
                width: 158.016,
                height: 55,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colours.black,
                    image: DecorationImage(
                      image: AssetImage("assets/images/xuriti-white.png"),
                      fit: BoxFit.fill,
                    ))),
            const SizedBox(height: 70),
            SizedBox(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/images/logo1.svg"),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 70,
            ),
            const Text(
              "“The question is not",
              style: TextStyles.textStyle2,
            ),
            const Text(
              "what you look at,but",
              style: TextStyles.textStyle2,
            ),
            const Text(
              "what you see.“",
              style: TextStyles.textStyle2,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Main.dart

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/push_notification/notification.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/routes/router.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/auth_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/company_details_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/password_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/profile_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/reward_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/trans_history_manager.dart';
import 'logic/view_models/transaction_manager.dart';
import 'models/helper/service_locator.dart';
import 'ui/routes/routnames.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
bool splashid = false;
void main() async {
  // enableFlutterDriverExtension();  // for appium mobile testing
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  // SharedPreferences prefrences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  // prefrences.remove("splashid");

  Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) async {
    FirebaseInitialization.sharedInstance.registerNotification();
    // FirebaseInitialization.sharedInstance.navigate();
    FirebaseInitialization.sharedInstance.configLocalNotification();
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('topic1');
    await FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
    );
  });

  runApp(const MyApp());

  Firebase.initializeApp().then((value) {
    FirebaseInitialization.sharedInstance.registerNotification();
    FirebaseInitialization.sharedInstance.configLocalNotification();
  });

  HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();

  await setupServiceLocator();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ScreenUtilInit(
        designSize: const Size(393, 786),
        minTextAdapt: true,
        splitScreenMode: true,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return MultiProvider(
            providers: [
              ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => getIt<AuthManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<CompanyDetailsManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<TransactionManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<PasswordManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<RewardManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<ProfileManager>()),
              ChangeNotifierProvider(
                  create: (context) => getIt<TransHistoryManager>()),
            ],
            child: MaterialApp(
                debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
                onGenerateRoute: Routers.generateRoute,
                navigatorKey: navigatorKey,
                initialRoute: splash),
          );
        });
  }
}

class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides {
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context) {
    String splashid = 'mainid';
    getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('splashid', splashid);
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback =
          (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true;
  }
}
```

Notification.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart' as inst;
import 'package:get/get_core/src/get_main.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/models/core/invoice_model.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/routes/router.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/screens/invoices_screens/invoices_screen.dart';
import 'package:xuriti/ui/screens/starting_screens/landing_Screen.dart';

import '../../logic/view_models/company_details_manager.dart';
import '../../main.dart';
import '../../models/helper/service_locator.dart';
import '../../models/services/dio_service.dart';

class FirebaseInitialization {
  FirebaseInitialization._privateConstructor();

  String? fcmToken;

  FirebaseMessaging firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  static FirebaseInitialization sharedInstance =
      FirebaseInitialization._privateConstructor();




  void registerNotification() async {
    
    try {
      if (Platform.isIOS) {
      } else {
        var val = await Permission.notification.isDenied;
        if (val) {}
      }

      var apnsToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getAPNSToken();
      fcmToken = await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken();
      String tkn = fcmToken.toString();
      

      log(fcmToken.toString());
      print('device token,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, $fcmToken');
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(
        (RemoteMessage message) async {
          final data = message.data;
          print('onMessage:******************* ${data['Inv_id']}');
          showNotification(message.data, message.notification);

          return;
        },
        onError: (error) {
          print(error);
        },
        
      );
    } catch (e) {
      return;
    }
  }

  //configure notification
  void configLocalNotification() async {
   
    FirebaseMessaging.instance
        .getInitialMessage()
        .then((RemoteMessage? message) async { 
      bool mainid = false;
      getIt<SharedPreferences>().setBool('mainid', mainid);
      getIt<SharedPreferences>().getString('id');
      bool checkid = true;
      getIt<SharedPreferences>().setBool('checkId', checkid);
      SharedPreferences shared = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      String? token = await getIt<SharedPreferences>().getString("token");

      if (message != null) {
         String splashid = 'splashid';
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('splashid', splashid);
        _handleMessage(message);
      }
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      bool checkid = true;
      getIt<SharedPreferences>().setBool('checkId', checkid);
      _handleMessage(message);
    });
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    DarwinInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        DarwinInitializationSettings();
    InitializationSettings initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,
    );
  }



  void _handleMessage(RemoteMessage message) async {
    String splashid = 'splashid';
    getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('splashid', splashid);
    if (message.data != null) {
      dynamic responseData =
          await getIt<DioClient>().getCompName(message.data["entityid"]);
      print(
          "response of comp name for notif ${responseData['company']['company_name']}");
      String entId = message.data['entityid'];

      getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('companyId', entId);

      String companyname = responseData['company']['company_name'];
      getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('companyName', companyname);

      String entityid = message.data['entityid'];
      getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('entityid', entityid);

      if (message.data['module'] == 'Invoices' &&
          message.data['target'] != null) {
        String targetid = message.data['target'];
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('targetid', targetid);
        bool checkid = true;
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setBool('checkId', checkid);
        dynamic responseData = await getIt<DioClient>().getInvDetails(targetid);
        var invoice = responseData['invoice'][0];
        String iddt = invoice['invoice_date'];
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('invDate', iddt);
        var intrest = invoice['paid_interest'];
        var disc = invoice['paid_discount'];
        var duedt = invoice['invoice_due_date'];
        String checkUndefined =
            invoice['bill_details']['gst_summary']['total_tax'];
        String billVal = invoice['bill_details']['gst_summary']['total_tax'];
        String invamt = invoice['invoice_amount'];
        String outAmt = invoice['outstanding_amount'].toString();
        int crLimt = invoice['buyer']['creditLimit'];
        var availCrd = invoice['buyer']['avail_credit'].toStringAsFixed(2);

        String availCr = availCrd.toString();
        String duedate = duedt.toString();
        String pDisc = disc.toString();

        String intr = intrest.toString();
        String compname = invoice['seller']['company_name'];
        String address = invoice['seller']['address'];
        String state = invoice['seller']['state'];
        String gstin = invoice['seller']['gstin'];
        dynamic creditLmt = invoice['buyer']['creditLimit'];
        dynamic crdlmt = creditLmt / 100000;
        dynamic crdLimit = crdlmt.toString();
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('crdLimit', crdLimit);

        dynamic availCredit = invoice['buyer']['avail_credit'];
        dynamic avlCredit = availCredit / 100000;
        dynamic availLimit = crdlmt.toString();
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('availLimit', availLimit);

        String invno = invoice['invoice_number'];
        String invstatus = invoice['invoice_status'];
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('invno', invno);
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('invstatus', invstatus);

        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('state', state);
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('gstin', gstin);

        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('address', address);

        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('billValue', billVal);
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('compname', compname);

        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('undefined', checkUndefined);

        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('inv_amt', invamt);

        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('outstanding', outAmt);

        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('duedate', duedate);

        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('paidintr', intr);
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('paidDisc', pDisc);

        navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(upcomingDetails);
      } else if (message.data['module'] == 'Invoices' &&
          message.data['target'] == null) {
        String splashid = 'splashid';
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('splashid', splashid);
        String entityid = message.data['entityid'];
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('entityid', entityid);

        navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(landing);

        var targetid = null;
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('targetid', targetid);
      } else if (message.data['module'] == 'Payments') {
        String splashid = 'splashid';
        getIt<SharedPreferences>().setString('splashid', splashid);
        getIt<CompanyDetailsManager>().getSellerList(message.data["entityid"]);

        navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(totalPayment);
      }
    }
  }

  void showNotification(
      Map<String, dynamic> data, RemoteNotification? remoteNotification) async {
    AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'com.transport.trnasportplus',
      'Transport plus',
      channelDescription: 'your channel description',
      playSound: true,
      enableVibration: true,
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
    );
    DarwinNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
        DarwinNotificationDetails();
    NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics,
        iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(
          0,
          remoteNotification?.title ?? "",
          remoteNotification?.body ?? '',
          platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: jsonEncode(data),
        )
        .then((value) {});
  }
}

Future<void> firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print("Handling a background message");
}
```